# are there other ways to write a multidimensional array in an array?

Tags: c++

I need to add an array to the array and I want to find the most convenient way for me.

I know only 2 options for adding here are examples.

```
int main() {
    int arr[5][6][8]{0};
    // option 1
    int& F = arr[1][0][1];
    F = 2;
    int L = arr[2][0][F];
    L = 5;

    // option 2
    arr[1][1][1] = 3;
    int Z = arr[2][1][arr[1][1][1]];
    Z = 7;
    cout << " ARR L " << L << "\n" << endl;
    cout << " ARR Z " << Z << "\n" << endl;


    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I need such a template to help me write readable code.
it's hard, I know it, but try to understand, please.
my template should save me from multidimensional arrays

Imagine that I will do something wild such as this.

```
arr[1][0][1] = 2; // in fact, the number is unknown, this is just an example. the program itself adds the numbers that are needed
int F& = arr[2][0][arr[1][0][1]] = 5;
arr[1][1][1] = 3;

int Z& = arr[arr[1][0][1]][arr[2][0][F]][arr[1][1][1]];

Z = 7;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205630/discussion-on-question-by-frenli-are-there-other-ways-to-write-a-multidimensiona).

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at your two options...

Option 1

```
// option 1
int& F = arr[1][0][1];
F = 2;
int& L = arr[2][0][F];   // added &
L = 5;
```

I changed `int L` to `int& L`, otherwise it does not make sense. Then the above has the same effect as

```
arr[1][0][1] = 2;
arr[2][0][2] = 5;
```

I think this is much more clear than your option1. No unnecessary variables and indirections, just plain assignment.

Option 2 (again changed to use a reference)

```
// option 2
arr[1][1][1] = 3;
int& Z = arr[2][1][arr[1][1][1]];
Z = 7;
```

This is the same as

```
arr[1][1][1] = 3;
arr[2][1][3] = 7;
```

Again I don't see a reason to make it more complicated than that.

PS: I know that this answer is most likely not what you want to hear, but I hope this will show you how to make it not more complicated than necessary, and perhaps you will be able to explain what additional requirements you have that you didnt mention yet.

Comment: I want something like this on a template
where T1, T2, T3 are the patterns
`arr[T1][T2][T3];
`
then my code will be like this
`int& Z = arr[T1][T2][T3];`
`Z = 7;`

Comment: @frenli if i didnt read your previous quesiton I would have no idea what you are talking about. Still I dont understand why you want a template. What "patterns"? Why not simply `arr[t1][t2][t3] = 7;` ? No need for template, no need for the reference...

Comment: Imagine that I will make many arrays that will have other arrays inside to get the right path.
after 3 arrays inside the array 3 times I get confused completely.
so the template would save me from a complicated understanding of multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @frenli nothing saves you from understanding what your code is supposed to do before you write it and honestly I think that is the real problem here. If you have 3 arrays then please provide an example with 3 arrays. There is only one in your code

Comment: @frenli btw I dont remember when I last time used a 2d array. From the top of my head I dont know any example other than for numerical calculations with matrices or higher order tensors that would be modeled appropriately with a higher dimensional array. Consider that comment from above suggesting "a class A that contains an array of class B where every B contains an array of class C" this sounds like the way to go

Comment: is there an example of this implementation? with array A, B, and C?

Comment: @frenli `struct C{}; struct B{ std::vector<C> c; }; struct A { std::vector<B> b; };` not possible to give more detailed example without more information from your side.

Comment: Of course, the C++ tag has just been removed by an edit....

Comment: @frenli why do you ask for a template and at the same time remove the C++ tag? Now I am confused. I am out of here (really have to catch a bus ;)